# "Google like" image preview button is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have some troubles with modifying code. I'm working on this ["google like" image preview](http://www.bootply.com/kn7MQ8RU39). As you can see first three image previews are working OK. I need the forth one to start working, since my HTML looks like the 4-th image and preview should only happen when user click on image "Quick view" div.

Script

```
<script>
    // hide all
    $('.descriptions .panel').hide();
    // show first
    //$('#descriptions .panel').eq(0).show();
    // handle img click
    $('#grid img').click(function(){
        // get index of the img that was clicked
        var idx = $(this).parent().index();
        var row = $(this).parent().parent().next('.row');
        // remove special style from all others
        $('#grid img').removeClass('highlight');
        // add a special style to the clicked image
        $(this).addClass('highlight');
        // hide all others
        $('.descriptions .panel').hide();
        // show desc for clicked img
        row.find('.descriptions .panel').eq(idx).show("slow","swing");
    });
</script>
```

Can you please help how to modify this code to solve my problem. If you need any additional information, please let me know and i will provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// hide all
$('.descriptions .panel').hide();
// handle img click
$('.col-md-3').click(function(){
// get index of the img that was clicked
var idx = $(this).index();

var row = $(this).parent().next('.row');
// remove special style from all others
$('#grid img').removeClass('highlight');
// add a special style to the clicked image
$(this).find('img').addClass('highlight');
// hide all others
$('.descriptions .panel').hide();
// show desc for clicked img
row.find('.descriptions .panel').eq(idx).show();
});
```

try this hope helps :)

Comment: half working :) It's working, but it must only when you click on image preview div. So i assume you must add some sort id="preview" on that div which trigger jquery code

Comment: so need to change some code for adding and removing class "highlight" right

Comment: i think so. I'm really weak with jquery, so i can't really tell you what to do :)

Comment: edited my answer added class to image also have a look bro :)

Comment: still having a problem. So let's say .col-md-3 triggers the effect.
I wan't to move this effect on "col-md-4 product-wishlist" if you check bootply, because i wan't this effect only happen when user click on preview...

Comment: i think your are close to answer.

Comment: so 4th div need to show when user clicked on quick view only right thats only the issue right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107198/discussion-between-shiva-and-valor).